# An example of remotely controlled flight control surface?

Tags: flight-controls

I'm aware of hydraulic, mechanical, and electrical ways to control flight control surfaces on an aircraft, but are there any examples of control surfaces which are remotely controlled? Can you explain their working?
Also, will this system come under Remote Position Control (servomechanism), or is it something different?

Comment: Would RC models qualify?

Comment: Nope. Real commercial aircrafts.

Comment: By remote control do you mean wireless? I'd be extremely surprised if there was a case. Opens up hacking possibilities.

Comment: Hydraulic, mechanical, and electrical actuation already *is* remote control of control surfaces. Can you describe better what you have in mind? Do you mean wireless? Do you mean remote control from cockpit, or from ground?

Comment: I mean remote control from the cockpit. I have an assignment on Remote Position Control (the servo-mechanism topic in control engineering), and they are specifically asking for an aircraft's control surface which is **controlled remotely**, and then we have to explain the operation of this RPC (remote position controller).

Comment: @HoodedSilhouette98 No, really, what do you mean by "remotely controlled"? The control surfaces are controlled from the cockpit. They are not in the cockpit. Therefore, in the ordinary English langauge sense of the term, they are remotely controlled. What do _you_ mean when you use the words "remotely controlled"?

Comment: "hydraulic, mechanical, and electrical" are power technologies for actuators possibly controlled by RPC. First it must be clarified if *remote* is related to the distance (or the media e.g. wire or radio) between pilot interface (or autopilot) and RPC or  between RPC and actuator. The only difference I can see is that the RPC must receive a feedback from the actuator in order to know its current position.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yeah I understand that all flight controls are obviously controlled from the cockpit. At first I thought that maybe my assignment asks about _wireless_ control of control surfaces like rudder. Upon second thought I feel that this is highly unlikely to happen, and maybe remote control just means staying in the cockpit and controlling. So here's the exact question:
**Select an aircraft control surface that is controlled remotely, then explain the operation of this remote position controller**

Comment: This in bold^ is all I've been asked @mins so it'd be great if you guys can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: From the bold extract, it seems the question boils down to "explain how a RPC works for a given control surface".

Comment: And how can we explain that? What is to be mentioned? Just the basic block diagram and a feedback loop? @mins

Comment: @HoodedSilhouette98 If you want clarification on what the exercise means, you should ask the person who actually set the exercise, not random people on the internet. We can't read their mind.